# Removing lines with specific words

Tags: emacs

I have a text file with multiple lines such as:

```
amanda: foo
robert: bla
amanda: bar
peter: da
```

I'd like to remove all lines with `amanda`. I use `ctrl-s` and kill each line individually. Is possible to remove all lines at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`M-x delete-matching-lines`. It's possible to use regular expression.

Comment: a.k.a. `flush-lines`, which is a bit shorter to type.

Comment: You might want to elaborate your answer to make it more complete, such as saying that either command applies to the part of the buffer after the point or to the region and that a regular expression that works for the example is `^amanda.*`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `query-replace-regexp` with a regular expression of `^.*amanda.*$` to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Although [@Marcos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754309/596361) is idiomatic one (you should use it), let's explore other variants. Let's say you have a text buffer and you want to delete a line containing `li` in it:

```
Vladimir
Ilich
Ulyanov
```

Remember, that `^` matches beginning of line and `$` end of line in regex. `$` doesn't touch the newline character after the line, so replace with regex `^.*li.*$` will produce an empty line, as per [@ataylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754316/596361):

```
Vladimir

Ulyanov
```

For some reason it's impossible to match before `^` and after `$` in regex, therefore `\s-^.*li.*$` nor `^.*li.*$\s-` won't work. Note, `\s-` matches any whitespace character, (i.e. space, tab, newline and carriage return), so intuitively the regexes should've deleted the newline too, as newline is the only possible whitespace character before `^` or after `$`. To match exactly newline, you should enter it verbatim, <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> by default. Emacs frequently denotes the newline in separate font color as `^J`, it's not a sequence of `^` and `J`, but a single character, please pay attention.

Therefore to delete a line containing `li`, you could run command `query-replace-regexp` on string `^.*li.*^J`, where `^J` is newline:

```
Vladimir
Ulyanov
```